# How to start first line in text view(paragraph) in middle - android

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I am new to Android. I have a paragraph in `string` which looks like below

```
String my_paragraph ="Software is a set of instructions, data or programs used to operate computers and execute specific tasks. It is the opposite of hardware, which describes the physical aspects of a computer. Software is a generic term used to refer to applications, scripts and programs that run on a device."
textView.setText(my_paragraph);
```

I want to display it in the Text View like this below image:

[image]

But what I got is I added below

[image]

I want the first line in text view(paragraph) should starts in the middle. I don't want to add leading spaces in `string`. I don't know how to achieve this. Please help me with some solutions.

Comment: why would you want to start in the middle? that might give us a clue for solutions

Comment: @ariefbayu does there really have to be a reason ? this could just be a design requirement or something OP has to achieve

Comment: @ariefbayu, Thanks for the response. I want to show some questions with answers in my app. so for answers text view, I want it to start in middle.

Comment: because as it is right now, I don't see a way other than prepending the strings with a bunch of white space...

Answer (score 5):

Android has libraries that can do this for you. I found an old post with a great how to use the `SpannableString` and `LeadingMarginSpan` libraries.

The question can be found at: [What is Leading Margin in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038931/what-is-leading-margin-in-android)

Comment: i think this is the best solution you'll find for this, but i wouldn't consider this question a duplicate of the one you've mentioned here. good find

Comment: I agree, this solution looks "more pro", mine is just a shortcut without way of defining size of indetation :)

Answer (score 2):

try to add `\t` or `\u0009` (tabulator character) at the begining of `String` - this is a symbol of default indetation for paragraphs

```
textView.setText("\u0009" + my_paragraph);
```

Comment: ah, I was busy testing this by the time you wrote your answer, this looks nicer than mine :)